# Change responsive logo slideshow from horizontal to vertical sliding

Tags: javascript, css, slider

```
var displayWaitMessage=true;    // Display a please wait message while images are loading?
var activeImage = false;
var imageGalleryLeftPos = false;
var imageGalleryWidth = false;
var imageGalleryObj = false;
var maxGalleryXPos = false;
var slideSpeed = -1;
var imageGalleryCaptions = new Array();
function startSlide(e)
{
    if(document.all)e = event;
    var id = this.id;
    if(this.id=='arrow_right'){
        slideSpeedMultiply = Math.floor((e.clientX - this.offsetLeft) / 5);
        slideSpeed = -1*slideSpeedMultiply;
        slideSpeed = Math.max(-10,slideSpeed);
    }else{
        slideSpeedMultiply = 10 - Math.floor((e.clientX - this.offsetLeft) / 5);
        slideSpeed = 1*slideSpeedMultiply;
        slideSpeed = Math.min(10,slideSpeed);
        if(slideSpeed<0)slideSpeed=10;
    }
}

function releaseSlide()
{
    var id = this.id;
    slideSpeed=-1;
}

function gallerySlide()
{
    if(slideSpeed!=0){
        var leftPos = imageGalleryObj.offsetLeft;
        leftPos = leftPos/1 + slideSpeed;
        if(leftPos>maxGalleryXPos){
            leftPos = maxGalleryXPos;
            slideSpeed = -1;

        }
        if(leftPos<minGalleryXPos){
            leftPos = minGalleryXPos;
            slideSpeed=1;
        }

        imageGalleryObj.style.left = leftPos + 'px';
    }
    setTimeout('gallerySlide()',50);

}

function showImage()
{
    if(activeImage){
        activeImage.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=50)';
        activeImage.style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
    this.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=100)';
    this.style.opacity = 1;
    activeImage = this;
}

function initSlideShow()
{
    document.getElementById('arrow_left').onmousemove = startSlide;
    document.getElementById('arrow_left').onmouseout = releaseSlide;
    document.getElementById('arrow_right').onmousemove = startSlide;
    document.getElementById('arrow_right').onmouseout = releaseSlide;


    imageGalleryObj = document.getElementById('theImages');
    imageGalleryLeftPos = imageGalleryObj.offsetLeft;
    imageGalleryWidth = document.getElementById('galleryContainer').offsetWidth - 80;
    maxGalleryXPos = imageGalleryObj.offsetLeft;
    minGalleryXPos = imageGalleryWidth - document.getElementById('slideEnd').offsetLeft;
    var slideshowImages = imageGalleryObj.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
    for(var no=0;no<slideshowImages.length;no++){
        slideshowImages[no].onmouseover = showImage;
    }

    var divs = imageGalleryObj.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
    for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
        if(divs[no].className=='imageCaption')imageGalleryCaptions[imageGalleryCaptions.length] = divs[no].innerHTML;
    }
    gallerySlide();
}

function showPreview(imagePath,imageIndex){
    var subImages = document.getElementById('previewPane').getElementsByTagName('IMG');
    if(subImages.length==0){
        var img = document.createElement('IMG');
        document.getElementById('previewPane').appendChild(img);
    }else img = subImages[0];

    if(displayWaitMessage){
        document.getElementById('waitMessage').style.display='inline';
    }
    document.getElementById('largeImageCaption').style.display='none';
    img.onload = function() { hideWaitMessageAndShowCaption(imageIndex-1); };
    img.src = imagePath;

}
function hideWaitMessageAndShowCaption(imageIndex)
{
    document.getElementById('waitMessage').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('largeImageCaption').innerHTML = imageGalleryCaptions[imageIndex];
    document.getElementById('largeImageCaption').style.display='block';

}
window.onload = initSlideShow;
```

http://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-logo-slideshow/

I need to know how to change from horizontal to vertical sliding? Is there a simple way to achieve that? I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: This seems like it would be a good question for the developer of the plugin you are using. Also, what's with all the dots?

Comment: Sorry for the dots, couldn't post my question without them because there was too little text in relation to the code.